# Flying through Istanbul with ID and not Passport

Tags: transit, paperwork, turkey, lithuanian-citizens

I will be travelling from Vilnius to Istanbul, and from Istanbul to Ljubljana. It is a connected flight with Turkish Airlines. Can I fly with only my ID? I do not have a passport.

Comment: I'm guessing these are 2 separate flights and you will leave the airplane in Istanbul and board a different one for the next leg?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: It is connected flight, same airlines, one after another

Comment: I am lithuanian

Comment: I would not leave the airport

Comment: No such thing as a "connected flight". I'm guessing you meant a single ticket with two flights. Which is quite different than, say, a single flight that stops in two cities, and you don't have to get off the plane.

Comment: @dda the phrase "connect*ing* flight" is, however, in common use.

Comment: @phoog connectING flightS, yeah. Connected flight, no. The OP seems to be under the false impression he's on a Vilnius-Ljubljana flight. Which it sure isn't.

Comment: @Chris Doesn't matter. You can Change flights in Istanbul on your ID if not leaving the transit area. The check-in staff told you so yourself, and I promise you they're right

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you are allowed to transit in Istanbul without leaving the transit area, as long as you can enter Slovenia (which you can).

However, many check-in agents are not aware of this, because of how poorly Timatic, the database used by them, has described this in the past. After I discussed this with my IATA contact, the database was slightly modified.

It now says (for Turkey):

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   - Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a
>     third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the
>     international transit area of the airport **and have documents
>     required for the next destination**.

Even so, although you **can** fly, I would strongly recommend you to e-mail Baltic Ground Services (the check-in company responsible for Turkish Airlines in Vilnius) at supervisor.phs@bgs.aero, ops@bgs.aero and vnoops@thy.com (yes, send to all three), and ask if they know this.

Ask if they are aware that, to transit at Istanbul **without** leaving the transit area, you do **not** need documents required to **enter** Turkey, only to enter Slovenia, and tell them that you're travelling to Slovenia on your Lithuanian ID.

If they say you can't fly, insist that they check with Turkish Airlines (they can contact a special department)

Comment: To whoever downvoted, please tell me how this is wrong

Comment: Thank you, I reached to them and was told that I can fly to Turkey with my ID as long as I do not leave the transit zone

Comment: Just a comment. Several years ago we flew from Crete (Greece) via Istanbul (just stopover to pick up more passengers - we did not leave the plane) to Amsterdam - our home country. Normally this is intra-Schengen but because of the stopover in Istanbul we did have to pass immigration.

Comment: So you needed your passport?

Comment: @Chris Passport or Dutch official ID card as Turkey accepts those for Dutch citizens. But you will have to pass immigration.

Comment: @PaulPalmpje Makes no sense. If you didn't leave the plane, that means you only cleared immigration in Crete and Amsterdam. And OP would **definitely** have been fine with their ID for that trip as well

Comment: @Chris Paul's comment doesn't make sense. He says they didn't leave the plane, but yet had to clear immigration. Even when getting off the plane, Istanbul has transit security to bypass immigration. So the only immigration Paul could have cleared was at Crete and Amsterdam. You as a Lithuanian would've been perfectly fine

Comment: @Chris Good the check-in staff knew :) To be safe, print their e-mail message in case the specific agent you get at bag drop and/or the gate in Vilnius is an amateur.

Comment: @Coke, Sorry I was to quick. We stayed on the plane in Istanbul and only had to pass immigration in Crete and Amsterdam. And National ID was acceptable - but this depends on country of citizenship. But if an ID was not acceptable then it's likely that we would not have been allowed to board in Crete.

Comment: @PaulPalmpje "National ID was acceptable - but this depends on country of citizenship" The ID needs to be acceptable for Greece and the Netherlands, or in OP's case for Lithuania and Slovenia. That's it. Not all check-in agents know this, but thankfully the ones in Vilnius turned out to be informed.

Comment: @PaulPalmpje I'm from Sweden and officially cannot use my ID to enter Turkey, but they've always been fine with it (except that time when they didn't think it was me on the photo). If entering by air I buy a throwaway connection to Ercan (which I later cancel, getting the taxes back) in order for check in in Zurich to issue my boarding pass. Because for that itinerary, my ID only has to be valid for Switzerland and North Cyprus.